# Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'. Failed to execute aapt

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, apk, ionic-native

I get this error when I deploy my ionic app:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
    > Failed to execute aapt

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 12s
        at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\KING WOODE\Desktop\testapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
        at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
    (node:5560) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
    (node:5560) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: What is the Cordova android platform version? you can know it by running "ionic info" command

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

`cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove android platform from the project and reinstall the android platform.

remove android platform :

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

Install android platform :

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

then try to build the project again, if it will not work , try to remove plugins folder and reinstall cordova plugins again.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [cordova-android-support-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release) plugin. It "aligns various versions of the Android Support libraries specified by other plugins to a specific version."

> Some Cordova plugins include [Android Support Libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html) to faciliate them. Most commonly, these are now included into the Cordova project by specifying them as Gradle dependencies (see the [Cordova plugin spec documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#framework)). (…) The problem arises when these plugins specify different versions of the support libraries. This can cause build failures to occur. (…) To resolve these version collisions, this plugin injects a Gradle configuration file into the native Android platform project, which overrides any versions specified by other plugins, and forces them to the version specified in its Gradle file.